# Creating an options Menu with pictures

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Im trying to make my app more colourful and add pictures to the menu. The menu shows just after the splash screen and works fine but I can't add pictures. I just want to have the pictures  beside each line of text. Everything i've tried involving listview tutorials I have had to add more classes and .xml files and still haven't worked. Here's the Menu.java class im using:

```
package com.interviewme;
/**
* This class is the menu page to redirect the user to any page they want
*/


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {


//names of classes to appear in the menu page
String classes []= {"Play", "About", "InterviewTips",
"Preparing", "Python" , "MySQL"};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter <String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,          classes));

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String positionClicked = classes [position];

    //try catch to catch exceptions and create new intent for whatever class is chosen
    try {
        Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.interviewme." +positionClicked);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent (Menu.this, ourclass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}








Here's the activity_menu.xml code:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#DEED34" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Here's also the tutroials I was following but could not get to work:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Can you be more specific about how those tutorials and your existing code aren't working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have pictures in your list view then you will have to add `ImageView` and `TextView` in your layout file, make a custom adapter class which extends `ArrayAdapter`, override `getView` method in that class to set your layout.
And then write -

```
setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, classes));
```

Instead of -

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter <String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
```

`MyAdapter` is the class which extends `ArrayAdapter`(you will have to make this class)

Refer to your own link of http://mkyong.com and see custom `ArrayAdapter` example.